# Placeholders are not showing variable values in ValidationMessages.properties file in Hibernate validation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I am using Hibernate validation in Spring Boot project. Though I am able to read messages from `ValidationMessage.properties` file and also arguments in curly braces as `{min}`, `{max}`:

```
Size.accountRequestBean.firmName=size should  be between {min} and {max}
```

**ValidationMessages.properties**

```
Size.accountRequestBean.firmName={0} should  be between {1} and {2}
```

But when i use `Size.accountRequestBean.firmName={0} should  be between {1} and {2}` the message displayed is `{0}` should be between `{1}` and `{2}`:

> expected :size should  be between 2 and 30.

**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Bean.java**

```
public class Bean {

    @Size(min=2, max=30,message="{Size.accountRequestBean.firmName}")
    private String firmName;
}
```

**Validation dependencies I am Using:**

```
<!-- Hibernate Validator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

So please suggest where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `ValidationMessage.properties` file to `messages.properties` (by default Spring expects to find it under the `resources` folder) and put the following properties inside it:

```
bean.hasErrors=Please fix the following errors
bean.firmName=Firm Name
Size.bean.firmName={0} should  be between {2} and {1}
```

*Note the order of precedence here is: **`code.objectName.fieldName`**. And `objectName` must be the same as your class name, so instead `accountRequestBean` put just `bean` (as your object `Bean.java`).*

---

Then, you can omit the `message` key in `@Size` annotation. When you use `messages.properties` file Spring Boot automatically get its messages:

```
public class Bean {
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String firmName;

    // getter, setter
}
```

---

Make sure you use `@Valid` annotation in your controller to use `Bean` validation, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doBean", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doBean (@Valid Bean checkoutCommand, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "form";
    }
    return "success";
}
```

---

Please look for the [complete code example](https://gist.github.com/DimaSanKiev/e766fb3e499676c991f35302fb9bf0c0).

You should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: I have seen somewhere this has been shown in one of the video in Spring MVC project.I am providing the link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x09tx_XrnXE.Is anything related that i am doing in springboot?

Comment: I have done all changes but getting the same result.Is there some reason i am doing in spring boot.I am not getting any answer from Internet even i have done a lot of POC's but still stuck.

Comment: can there be reason related to spring version. On hibernate higher version i already have checked issue remain same.

Comment: btw, if you use Spring Boot you can add `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency and remove that two validation dependencies you added, they are already included. I use `1.4.1.RELEASE` version but it must be working on previous versions as well. What is actually your error is?

Comment: I am not getting error. I am getting message displayed as {0} should be between {1} and {2}.

Comment: but i should get firmName should be between 2 and 30. i mean to say 0th argument should be fieldname ,{1} and {2} should be min and max attributes length. expected output:) firmName should be between 2 and 30

Comment: It's hard to tell where is your mistake. Post your full example code somewhere or download my example and see what's different.

Answer (score 0):

On my project the problem was in this setting:

```
var messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
```

after

```
setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false)
```

all worked